# Extract first and last row of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**How can I extract the first and last rows of a given dataframe as a new dataframe in pandas?**

I've tried to use `iloc` to select the desired rows and then `concat` as in:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,5), 'b':['a','b','c','d']})
pd.concat([df.iloc[0,:], df.iloc[-1,:]])
```

but this does not produce a pandas dataframe:

```
a    1
b    a
a    4
b    d
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some of the other answers **duplicate** the first row if the frame only contains a single row. If that's a concern

`df[0::len(df)-1 if len(df) > 1  else 1]`

works even for single row-dataframes.

Example: For the following dataframe this will not create a duplicate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b':['a']})
df2 = df[0::len(df)-1 if len(df) > 1  else 1]

print df2

   a  b
0  1  a
```

whereas this does:

```
df3 = df.iloc[[0, -1]]

print df3 

   a  b
0  1  a
0  1  a
```

because the single row is the first AND last row at the same time.

Comment: Good point. Can you provide an example output to make a more complete answer

Answer (score 208):

I think the most simple way is `.iloc[[0, -1]]`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,5), 'b':['a','b','c','d']})
df2 = df.iloc[[0, -1]]
    
print(df2)

   a  b
0  1  a
3  4  d
```

Comment: mind that this duplicates the first row if the frame only contains a single row

Comment: note that `iloc` is required for `df` when using last element index (-1), which makes it different from lists and non-last indices

Answer (score 115):

You can also use `head` and `tail`:

```
In [29]: pd.concat([df.head(1), df.tail(1)])
Out[29]:
   a  b
0  1  a
3  4  d
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution as it applies to everything. I was getting "index position out of bounds" errors when trying to use `.iloc` on slices of a frame (which makes sense as the index changes) did not want to `reset_index` as the current index was important

Answer (score 8):

I think you can try add parameter `axis=1` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), because output of `df.iloc[0,:]` and `df.iloc[-1,:]` are `Series` and transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print df.iloc[0,:]
a    1
b    a
Name: 0, dtype: object

print df.iloc[-1,:]
a    4
b    d
Name: 3, dtype: object

print pd.concat([df.iloc[0,:], df.iloc[-1,:]], axis=1)
   0  3
a  1  4
b  a  d

print pd.concat([df.iloc[0,:], df.iloc[-1,:]], axis=1).T
   a  b
0  1  a
3  4  d
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can use [`take`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.take.html):

```
In [3]: df.take([0, -1])
Out[3]: 
   a  b
0  1  a
3  4  d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same style as in large datasets:

```
x = df[:5]
y = pd.DataFrame([['...']*df.shape[1]], columns=df.columns, index=['...'])
z = df[-5:]
frame = [x, y, z]
result = pd.concat(frame)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
                     date  temp
0     1981-01-01 00:00:00  20.7
1     1981-01-02 00:00:00  17.9
2     1981-01-03 00:00:00  18.8
3     1981-01-04 00:00:00  14.6
4     1981-01-05 00:00:00  15.8
...                   ...   ...
3645  1990-12-27 00:00:00    14
3646  1990-12-28 00:00:00  13.6
3647  1990-12-29 00:00:00  13.5
3648  1990-12-30 00:00:00  15.7
3649  1990-12-31 00:00:00    13
```

Comment: Nice... although it does have the same type of duplication challenge for lists with <10 elements. Seems you might need to wrap things in an if statement to get things to work for shorter dataframes.